# Allowing mobile money payments on website using phones

Tags: api, payment

Recently in Africa, there has been an uprise of third party websites that offer API for managing mobile money transactions. For example, if I have to pay for a service on a website, I would be given a mobile number to send mobile money to with a certain code. If transaction is successful, I would be instantly and automatically a text with an unique reference number to input in the site in order to get live credits to purchase some services.

I would like to understand the process as I think it's based on API given by the mobile money service providers (eg MTN). I already have built a shopping cart website  but I want you to help me to integrate this kind of method of payment that is called *Mobile Money* into my website. Does anyone here have any checkout page with Mobile Money payment method?

Comment: what i dont understand is how ur server knows you've received a mobile payement and generate a ref number in yoour db for later verification..

Comment: After years, i have developed my own solution that solves these issues in under 5minutes. best of all, its free. Start accepting mobile money payments worldwide using mtn and airtel mobile money https://www.easypay.co.ug/kb/knowledge-base/open-mobile-money-api-uganda-mtn-airtel/

Answer (score 2):

I think its possible to achieve that. You can use kannel or any other SMS gateway. Basically send a transaction key to the client's mobile number, which they will then as a message in their mobile money transaction.

If the mobile money transaction is complete, the operator (mtn, zap, etc) should send you an SMS confirmation, and ideally you can then pick the transaction key from the message field.

Comment: I think the problem is more complex than you try to explain. First, the operator should open its API that is I don't think it is already done!

Comment: https://www.easypay.co.ug/kb/knowledge-base/open-mobile-money-api-uganda-mtn-airtel/

Comment: This is now possible with platforms like [MoneyUnify](https://moneyunify.com), which allows you to collect and request payments from networks like Airtel, MTN, Zamtel, etc.  And with MoneyUnify, you do this under a single API request. Check out their [documentation here](https://github.com/blessedjasonmwanza/MoneyUnify).